# is insert into.. select statement transactional?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

do i need to use transaction to provide all or not proposition for the following insert process?

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 , column2)
SELECT  col1, col2
FROM    table2
```

expecting average row-count from table2 is around 150 and target database is ms sql server 2008 r2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to. A single SQL statement is already in a transaction by default so there is no way that you will partually insert results or that results will be meanwhile moderated by another transaction. The fact that 2 tables are involved doesn't change the fact that a single SQL statement is used.

Comment: In the absence of an explicit transaction, each statement if effectively in its own transaction. MS calls it autocommit -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As your simple insert will not needed. 
**By default sqlserver manage this thing and at the end commit whatever you did.**

If you explicitly want when multiple statement executed of insert/update or when you want to parent/child inserted in single unit of work, then you use transaction as

```
tran
declare @parentId int =0;
insert statement ---parent

set @parentId= @@identity

insert statement --child entry
values ( @parentId,...)

If @@ERROR  > 0 then
ROLLBACK
else 
COMMIT
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4451/SQL-Server-Transactions-and-Error-Handling

or you can use try catch block as c# in sqlserver side too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175976.aspx